# Resize Image<Gray, byte> without scaling. Emgu CV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am using Image.InRange to create a mask from an image.  In order to keep performance at its maximum, I am using the Image.ROI to crop the image and prior to using the InRange method.  In order to to actually work with image though, I need it to have the same dimensions as the original, but all that is apparent to me is how to scale an image, not change the dimensions preserving the image.

Here is the code in question:

```
public Image<Gray, byte> Process(Image<Bgr, byte> frameIn, Rectangle roi)
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> rectFrame = null;
        Image<Gray, byte> mask = null;
        if (roi != Rectangle.Empty)
        {
            rectFrame = frameIn.Copy(roi);
        }
        else
        {
            rectFrame = frameIn;
        }

        if (Equalize)
        {
            rectFrame._EqualizeHist();
        }


        mask = rectFrame.InRange(minColor, maxColor);

        mask ._Erode(Iterations);
        mask ._Dilate(Iterations);

        if (roi != Rectangle.Empty)
        {
            //How do I give the image its original dimensions?
        }

        return mask;
    }
```

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: Could you show what you've done/put this in the form of a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you wish to return the mask with the same size as framIn the easiest way is to copy the mask to a new image that has the same size as framIn. You could if your application isn't time sensitive make mask the same size of framIn set its ROI and then do your operations. This does take longer to process and isn't the best practice.

Anyway here is hopefully the code your after if not let me know and I'll correct it accordingly.

```
if (roi != Rectangle.Empty)
{
    //Create a blank image with the correct size
    Image<Gray, byte> mask_return = new Image<Gray, byte>(frameIn.Size);
    //Set its ROI to the same as Mask and in the centre of the image (you may wish to change this)
    mask_return.ROI = new Rectangle((mask_return.Width - mask.Width) / 2, (mask_return.Height - mask.Height) / 2, mask.Width, mask.Height);
    //Copy the mask to the return image
    CvInvoke.cvCopy(mask, mask_return, IntPtr.Zero);
    //Reset the return image ROI so it has the same dimensions
    mask_return.ROI = new Rectangle(0, 0, frameIn.Width, frameIn.Height);
    //Return the mask_return image instead of the mask
    return mask_return;
}

return mask;
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Chris